# understanding and following z3 master source code of smt2lib parser

Tags: z3

I want to understand z3 master source code.I followed the calls from main file for input kind of smt2. for this type of input main file calls smtlib_frontend file via the below code(line 341):

```
case IN_SMTLIB_2:
memory::exit_when_out_of_memory(true, "(error \"out of memory\")");
return_value = read_smtlib2_commands(g_input_file);
 break;
```

and then this method calls smt2parser via(line 128) :

```
 result = parse_smt2_commands(ctx, in);
```

in smt2parser.cpp and in the called method :

```
 bool parse_smt2_commands(cmd_context & ctx, std::istream & is, bool  
 interactive, params_ref const & ps) {
    smt2::parser p(ctx, is, interactive, ps);
    return p();
```

}

I have 2 problem :
 first : what does p() mean? parser class just has one constructor (parser (ctx, is, interactive, ps)) and don't have any method with the name of p.

second : after calling this method, the caller graph will be disconnected while this file is the main class for parsing smt2lib in z3 and has a method with the name "parse_cmd()" that seems it is main method for starting the parsing operation. but there is no refrence to this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines of code:

```
smt2::parser p(ctx, is, interactive, ps);
return p();
```

mean "construct an object of type smt2::parser with name p" (via the constructor that takes 4 arguments) and then call the function p.operator() (with no arguments) and return its result; see [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.cpp#L2638). (Redefining what the parentheses mean is called "operator overloading" and is a concept that exists in many languages.)

SMT2 is a command language, i.e., a benchmark file contains a series of commands, each of which will trigger a call to parse_cmd.